# GRASS GIS 7.8 Delete mapset from command line

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, grass-7.8

Within GRASS GIS 7.8, a new mapset can be created using `g.mapset -c mapset=mapset location=location`, but is it possible to delete a mapset from the command line? I know that a mapset can be removed from the user's path using `g.mapsets`, but I want to delete the files and directory that compose the mapset.

Comment: There is no way deleting mapsets from command-line without using the GUI so far I am aware of. There was a tickets for this feature as of end of last year at https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3582#comment:1. Maybe deleting from user path using 'g.mapsets' and use command-line/python folder deletion is an alternative if you need this in a script?

Comment: AFAIK, just delete the directory (from the command line), and it's gone :-)